# How to use Java's DecimalFormat for "smart" currency formatting?

Tags: java, formatting, decimalformat

I'd like to use Java's DecimalFormat to format doubles like so:

```
#1 - 100 -> $100
#2 - 100.5 -> $100.50
#3 - 100.41 -> $100.41
```

The best I can come up with so far is:

```
new DecimalFormat("'$'0.##");
```

But this doesn't work for case #2, and instead outputs "$100.5"

Edit:

A lot of these answers are only considering cases #2 and #3 and not realizing that their solution will cause #1 to format 100 as "$100.00" instead of just "$100".

Comment: Btw, using doubles to represent monetary values is a bad idea: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3730019/56285

Comment: Btw, most prices are represented as `double` (or `int` with fixed precision) in banks.

Answer (score 23):

Does it have to use `DecimalFormat`?

If not, it looks like the following should work:

```
String currencyString = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(currencyNumber);
//Handle the weird exception of formatting whole dollar amounts with no decimal
currencyString = currencyString.replaceAll("\\.00", "");
```

Comment: 'currencyString.replaceAll( regexp, String)' is inefficient in this case. 'currencyString = currencyString.replace( ".00", "" );' is much more efficient.
replaceAll requires compiling a Pattern, creating a Matcher, etc. This can be quite costly, especially if the code is executing in a display loop on Mobile devices with limited resources (Android).

Comment: Worth noting that `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()` will only format with $ if your `Locale` is set to US. To specify the currency explicitly you can pass a `Locale` - for example `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US)` here

Answer (score 9):

Use NumberFormat:

```
NumberFormat n = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US); 
double doublePayment = 100.13;
String s = n.format(doublePayment);
System.out.println(s);
```

Also, don't use doubles to represent exact values. If you're using currency values in something like a Monte Carlo method (where the values aren't exact anyways), double is preferred.

See also: [Write Java programs to calculate and format currency](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-06-2001/jw-0601-cents.html)

Comment: this doesn't work for case #1 ... it formats 100 as "$100.00" instead of "$100"

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't cover the setMinimumFractionDigits(0) case.

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
new DecimalFormat("'$'0.00");
```

Edit:

I Tried

```
DecimalFormat d = new DecimalFormat("'$'0.00");

        System.out.println(d.format(100));
        System.out.println(d.format(100.5));
        System.out.println(d.format(100.41));
```

and got

```
$100.00
$100.50
$100.41
```

Comment: this doesn't work for case #1 ... it formats 100 as "$100.00" instead of "$100"

Comment: DecimalFormat("0.00") works for parsing into a double. Thank you for this simple answer

Answer (score 3):

Try using

```
DecimalFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
DecimalFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
```

Comment: it does! `code`public class Testing {

 /**
  * @param args
  */
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  double d = 100.5;
  DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("'$'0.##");
  df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
  df.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
  String currency = df.format(d);
  System.out.println(currency);

 }

}
`code`

Comment: @Peter, did you mean case #1? That's where this doesn't seem to work (Java 1.6.0_22 on a mac), producing "$100.00" instead of "$100" which is what OP wanted.

Comment: @Jonik yes exactly, sorry for the mistype.  I've basically determined this is not possible using DecimalFormat and have moved onto other means to solve this problem.  Thanks!

Comment: Ok Youre right You can try to 'hack' it for case #1 if you test `code`if(currency.substring(currency.indexOf(".")).equals("00")) { currency = currency.substring(0,currency.indexOf(".")) } `code`

Answer (score 1):

You can check "is number whole or not" and choose needed number format.

```
public class test {

  public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(function(100d));
    System.out.println(function(100.5d));
    System.out.println(function(100.42d));
  }

  public static String function(Double doubleValue){
    boolean isWholeNumber=(doubleValue == Math.round(doubleValue));
    DecimalFormatSymbols formatSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.GERMAN);
    formatSymbols.setDecimalSeparator('.');

    String pattern= isWholeNumber ? "#.##" : "#.00";    
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(pattern, formatSymbols);
    return df.format(doubleValue);
  }
}
```

will give exactly what you want:

```
100
100.50
100.42
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following format:

DecimalFormat dformat = new DecimalFormat("$#.##");

Answer (score 1):

I know its too late. However following worked for me :

```
DecimalFormatSymbols otherSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.UK);
new DecimalFormat("\u00A4#######0.00",otherSymbols).format(totalSale);

 \u00A4 : acts as a placeholder for currency symbol
 #######0.00 : acts as a placeholder pattern for actual number with 2 decimal 
 places precision.
```

Hope this helps whoever reads this in future :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try by using two different `DecimalFormat` objects based on the condition as follows:

```
double d=100;
double d2=100.5;
double d3=100.41;

DecimalFormat df=new DecimalFormat("'$'0.00");

if(d%1==0){ // this is to check a whole number
    DecimalFormat df2=new DecimalFormat("'$'");
    System.out.println(df2.format(d));
}

System.out.println(df.format(d2));
System.out.println(df.format(d3));

Output:-
$100
$100.50
$100.41
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Java Money API to achieve this. (although this is not using DecialFormat)

```
long amountInCents = ...;
double amountInEuro = amountInCents / 100.00;

String customPattern; 
if (minimumOrderValueInCents % 100 == 0) {
    customPattern = "# ¤";
} else {
    customPattern = "#.## ¤";
}

Money minDeliveryAmount = Money.of(amountInEuro, "EUR");
MonetaryAmountFormat formatter = MonetaryFormats.getAmountFormat(AmountFormatQueryBuilder.of(Locale.GERMANY)
            .set(CurrencyStyle.SYMBOL)
            .set("pattern", customPattern)
            .build());

System.out.println(minDeliveryAmount);
```

Answer (score -1):

printf also works.

Example:

double anyNumber = 100;
printf("The value is %4.2f ", anyNumber);

Output:

The value is 100.00

4.2 means force the number to have two digits after the decimal. The 4 controls how many digits to the right of the decimal.

Comment: That does not handle adding commas for larger numbers, but it works given the examples.