# How to fetch 3 character in float?

Tags: java

I have Float value like 0.152545 I just want 0.1f.
How this is possible..
By using String I was get the String value.The following code show the result.

```
 String pass = pass.substring(0, Math.min(pass.length(), 3));
 pass=pass+"f";
```

This gives me String value like0.1f ,But I want only Float value like 0.1f.

Comment: Why don't you convert it to a float and set the precision you want?

Comment: Just a remark on usage: one tenth, 0.1, has no exact representation in bits, and the float is just an approximation (sum using 1/32, 1/64, 1/128, ...). So 1000 * 0.1 will not be 100.0.

Answer (score 6):

It would be appropriate place where you should use [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html), And `.#f` would be pattern for your case.

[Find more on Number formatting in java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html).

Some related question -

- [Show only two digit after decimal.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10959424/show-only-two-digit-after-decimal/10959430#10959430)
- [Formatting numbers using DecimalFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16583604/formatting-numbers-using-decimalformat/16583913#16583913)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a BigDecimal.

```
float f = 0.152545f;
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(f);
bd = bd.setScale(1, RoundingMode.DOWN);
f = bd.floatValue();
```

Works fine even if you have a float stored as a String.

```
String floatAsString = "0.152545";
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(floatAsString);
bd = bd.setScale(1, RoundingMode.DOWN);
float f = bd.floatValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.0");
format.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
format.setMaximumFractionDigits(1);
System.out.println(format.format(0.152545) + "f");
```

Answer (score -1):

How about

```
float new = Math.round( 10.0 * f ) / 10.0;
```

It won't be precise, as floats/doubles are just sums of finite series of 1/2^n, but might be good enough for you.

Perhaps you should be thinking about [presenting the float](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) with one significant decimal point and keep full precision internally?

Cheers,