# How can I round up to 3 Decimal places in Java such that .000 shoould be there at the end of the value even if it is a single digit number

Tags: java

I want to convert 10.5 to 10.500 in Java. How can I do it??

Comment: Is this for further calculation or is it for printing out the value? Can we presume the latter?

Comment: Are you sure you want to convert 10.5 to 105? Is that just a typo?

Comment: This shows that you should reread your question before posting it, I'd also create smaller titles and use more tags. Also, what *exactly* do you mean with "up" in  "round **up**"?

Comment: This might be a [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16583604/589259) although it kind of presumes knowing about `DecimalFormat`, and it doesn't strictly round **up** it seems to me.

Comment: “I want to convert 10.5 to 10.500 in Java. How can I do it?” By doing nothing.  They are numerically identical.

Answer (score 2):

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.000");
System.out.println(formatter.format(10.5));
```

Comment: OP updated their Q to fix a typo. You might want to adjust your A to fit now.

Comment: Might want to call `formatter.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.UP)`, since question title starts with *"How can I **round up** ..."*, though OP probably didn't mean it like that, but at least mention how to change the rounding mode.