# Formatting Columns in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a Money field in Sql server Table and mapping to double in hibernate.
how to format as 999,999?(three to three separate)

for example: 45000.0 ---> 45,000

Comment: Database and hibernate keep data, not format it. The view part of your application should answer for formatting data selected with hibernate from database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest not to do this at the SQL or hibernate layer. You should handle this in you UI layer. You can use Java's [DecimalFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) or see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379221/java-currency-number-format) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyClass {
    BigDecimal money;
    public static final NumberFormat NUMBER_FORMAT = new DecimalFormat(",###");

    @Column
    public BigDecimal getMoney() {
        return money;
    }

    @Transient
    public String displayMoney(){
       return NUMBER_FORMAT.format(money);
    }

}
```