# How to best get an actual value from a string formatted numer in Java?

Tags: java, string, numbers

Could you advise on what's the best approach to retrieveting an actual value from differently formatted string numbers?

Example:

I want to be able to pass in all these strings:

```
101,00
101.00
-101,00
-101.00
100,000.00
100.000,00
-100,000.00
-100.000,00
```

And get these returns from the method:

```
101.00
101.00
-101.00
-101.00
100000.00
100000.00
-100000.00
-100000.00
```

Should I just use string.replaceAll("","") or is there a better way?

Thanks

Comment: Looks similar of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379221/java-currency-number-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using replace all won't work. When you need is to find the last occurance of '.' or ',' and use that as your decimal place.

Based on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html

```
public static void main(String... args) throws ParseException {
    DecimalFormatSymbols dfs1 = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    dfs1.setDecimalSeparator('.');
    dfs1.setGroupingSeparator(',');

    DecimalFormat df1 = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00", dfs1);
    System.out.println(df1.format(-10000)+" parsed is "+df1.parse("-10,000.01"));

    DecimalFormatSymbols dfs2 = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    dfs2.setDecimalSeparator(',');
    dfs2.setGroupingSeparator('.');

    DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00", dfs2);
    System.out.println(df2.format(-10000)+" parsed is "+df2.parse("-10.000,01"));
}
```

prints

```
-10,000.00 parsed is -10000.01
-10.000,00 parsed is -10000.01
```

Comment: Well it would because when the method is called I already know the decimal separator from the application so I don;t have to account for that. So I can definitely do it like that but I wonder if there's a nicer solution to this issue.

Comment: @goe Using DecimalFormat could be considered nicer.