# Java / Android: from string to decimal or int

Tags: java, android

Thousand separator: "." (dot)
Decimal separator: "," (comma).
I live in Italy.

I'm getting from API this value (it's a string):

```
"balance":"1254.00".
```

In a case I need to convert it in an integer value:

```
1.254
```

without the decimal part (also if it is not zero, without round up or down).

In another case I could have (it's a string):

```
"balance":"1234.56"
```

And in that case I need

```
1.234,56
```

Going crazy with several functions, not getting my goal.

E.g. I tried:

```
NumberFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("#,##");
BigDecimal balance_numeric = new BigDecimal(this.raw_balance.replaceAll(",", ""));
balance = String.valueOf(numberFormat.format(balance_numeric));
```

And getting for first case (`1254`) an `12,54` , no sense for me.

Thank you very much.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25412801/2338006

Answer (score 0):

The code is pretty much self-explanatory. Do comment if you need help.  :)

```
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat();
DecimalFormatSymbols sm = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance();
sm.setDecimalSeparator(',');
sm.setGroupingSeparator('.');
format.setDecimalFormatSymbols(sm);
System.out.println(format.format(1254.02));
```

**EDIT 1**

There is an [alternative](http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/java/locale-140624.html) which I didn't know about.

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.ITALIAN);
DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat)nf;
```

You can use the Locale to do awesome stuff!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, the API always returns a decimal number. If the decimal part is zero you want the integer part of the number. If not, you wants the whole decimal number.

```
    String s = "1234.00";
    Double d = new Double(s);

    double f = d - d.longValue();
    if (f == .0) {
        // format d.longValue() as int
    } else {
        // format d as double
    }
```