# JavaFx TextField Currency format filter

Tags: java, javafx, textfield

I do get the price from the user but I want to filter the digits and puts, in each 3 digits like 123,123,123.

```
txtPrice.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
   if (!newValue.matches("\\d*")){
       txtPrice.setText(newValue.replaceAll("[^\\d]",""));
   }
});
```

Comment: have a look at TextFormatter - with it you can fine-tune formatting, validation and navigation on text input

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Currency Number format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379221/java-currency-number-format)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To format number as you specified, you may try this:

```
// Eg: format "123123123" as "123,123,123"
if (newValue.matches("\\d*")) {
    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###");
    String newValueStr = formatter.format(Double.parseDouble(newValue));

    txtPrice.setText(newValueStr);
}
```

Hope this help, good luck!

Comment: good to use a Format for the job, even better would be to use it inside a fx TextFormatter :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
textFieldUsername.setOnKeyTyped(event -> {
    String typedCharacter = event.getCharacter();
    event.consume();

    if (typedCharacter.matches("\\d*")) {
        String currentText = textFieldUsername.getText().replaceAll("\\.", "").replace(",", "");
        long longVal = Long.parseLong(currentText.concat(typedCharacter));
        textFieldUsername.setText(new DecimalFormat("#,##0").format(longVal));
    }
});
```

Comment: no, don't do the formatting in a key handler (will miss copied or otherwise updated text) plus don't do any manual formatting (will blow in different Locales)

Comment: this method works great but can we do it better? i did search about TextFormatter but i can't understand it i need to learn how to do this on my own so guys what should i learn and give me some good resources