# DecimalFormat ("$0.00") adding zeros and not putting decimal where it should go

Tags: java, decimalformat

For a class, I have to input a number of quarters, dimes, and nickels and output them as dollars.

If I input `4` quarters, `10` dimes, and `5` nickels, I get `$225.00`, not `$2.25`.

Can anyone help me, please?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.print("Enter Number of Quaters: ");
    Scanner quarter = new Scanner (System.in);
    int quarters = quarter.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter Number of Dimes: ");
    Scanner dime = new Scanner (System.in);
    int dimes = dime.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter Number of Nickels: ");
    Scanner nickel = new Scanner (System.in);
    int nickels = nickel.nextInt();

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("$0.00");
    System.out.print("The total is ");
    System.out.println(df.format((quarters * 25) + (dimes * 10) + (nickels * 5)));
}
```

Comment: I didn't check but I'm sure decimal format requires a decimal, not an `int`.  Convert to `double`, then format.

Comment: you have to divide ((quarters * 25) + (dimes * 10) + (nickels * 5)) by 100. You converted everything to cents and expecting dollars.

Comment: Also look at this answer, fourth answer down the list uses a currency format: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379221/java-currency-number-format  (Re. @AshraffAliWahab answer, you have to divide by `100.0`, not 100, which will still give you an `int`.)

Comment: Have you learned how to use `.printf` yet? Using %.2d in conjunction with / 100.0 is probably what your Prof. is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I know the following code is pretty hacky but if you don't have to use `DecimalFormat`, then this should format an `int` value representing cents to dollars, correctly:

```
int total = (quarters * 25) + (dimes * 10) + (nickels * 5);
String strTotal = (total<10 ? "0" + String.valueOf(total) : String.valueOf(total));
String formattedTotal = "$" + (strTotal.length()<3 ? "0" : strTotal.substring(0, strTotal.length()-2))
                            + "." + strTotal.substring(strTotal.length()-2, strTotal.length());

System.out.println(formattedTotal);
```